# What software and technology could help this deaf and blind student do math?

Tags: technology-in-education, software

I've got a very smart and capable student who needs to finish his college degree. He has severe limitations at this time. Because of a severe illness, he is unable to write and is now deaf and blind. However, he still retains enough sight that he can read on and use the computer.

We are trying to figure out how he can finish his degree requirements. We are looking for college-level software that can aid him in reading, writing, and calculating math. He will need to finish Business Math, Calculus, and Statistics.

What software could aid us in making this accomplishment spossible for him

Comment: Are you in a country such as the US where the government mandates equal educational opportunities for disabled students? If so, then you should have professionals available at your school who can help you with this -- you shouldn't have to ask online. E.g., at the California community college where I teach, we have a whole disabled student center. If you're in a poor country where resources like this aren't available, and asking people online is really your best option, then we may need to know more about your situation, e.g., what resources you actually *do* have available.

Comment: "deaf and blind. However, he still retains enough sight that he can read" — blind but can read?

Comment: Can he read Nemeth Braille? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemeth_Braille

Comment: @RustyCore: Blindness doesn't necessarily equate to a complete lack of vision.

Comment: This is at least the 4th time that something like this has been asked on ME.SE, and there's never been a really satisfying (or accepted!) answer to it. I think this is a very hard problem, that in my awareness may not be solvable. (1) https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/what-accessibility-is-available-to-the-blind-and-visually-impaired-students-and (2) https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/how-do-blind-people-learn-mathematics (3) https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/teaching-algebra-to-visually-impaired-or-blind-students

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what he needs (or needed) to finish his courses
is a screen-reader that can handle mathematics?
The answer to this question, [Are there screen readers that can read math equations?](https://www.washington.edu/doit/are-there-screen-readers-can-read-math-equations), is *Yes*: There are screen-readers that can handle
MathML. They rely on [MathPlayer](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/),
"a universal math reader that now enables math to be spoken in assistive technology products."

Answer (score 0):

Both edX and Coursera have free, quality courses:

- [edX Calculus](https://www.edx.org/learn/calculus)
- [Coursera Calculus](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=calculus)
- [edX Statistics](https://www.edx.org/learn/statistics)
- [Coursera Statistics](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=statistics)

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image from [Robert Ghrist's Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/single-variable-calculus).</sup>

---

Concerning accessibility, they are both US-based companies and subject to government-mandated requirements (as @BenCrowell details). Here are their accessibility statements:

- [edX accessibility](https://www.edx.org/accessibility)
- [Coursera accessibility](https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/209818883-Coursera-s-accessibility-policy)

Comment: Does edX offer college credit or just certificates?

Good info. Still, we are mainly asking about software that will help him write equations, etc and calculate. Software (think MS 
Word, Excel, etc).

Comment: @user4959691 You should that information into the question itself.

Comment: @user4959691: Good point. Perhaps I misunderstood.